# exit document.evaluate

Tags: javascript, xpath, greasemonkey, document.evaluate

I'm using using Greasemonkey. If the `xpathExpression` doesn't exist, the whole script will stop.

```
document.evaluate(
    xpathExpression,
    document,
    null,
    XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
    null);
```

Is there a way to stop that `document.evaluate` and continue to let the script run?

the error:
"Error: The expression is not a legal expression."

Comment: i used casablanca's method, it not that xpathexpression is undefined or empty. It just the xpath doesn't exist. Thanks both of you.

Comment: @guest:  If casablanca's method works for you, mark it as the answer. (Click the check mark.)

Comment: Not XPath question, but javascript code style (as in: How to deal with wrong parameter's value?)

Comment: @Alejandro: It **is** an XPath question.  The real issue is how to avoid an invalid search/selector -- which requires knowledge of XPath syntax and tools.

Comment: @Brock Adams: I don't agree. Where is the XPath expression to be corrected? This is like calling any function that it could throw an exception. Please, rollback your edition.

Comment: @Alejandro: `xpathExpression` contains the XPath expression to be corrected. The OP omitted necessary details and (currently) seems to be choosing the wrong approach, but the heart of this problem is that he has invalid XPath query/queries.  As the answers point out, try-catch is not a robust/efficient/smart way to deal with the problem.

Comment: @Alejandro: PS.  You could make a stronger argument that this is not a [greasemonkey] question.  Since neither the Q or the A really has anything to do with greasemonkey -- except that the OP stated that he happened to be using it (Just as he stated about XPath).  But, you don't advocate removing the GM tag -- Why not?

Comment: @Brock Adams: I see now where is your missundertood. In XPath 1.0, there is not syntactically correct expression trowing exceptions: there is no such thing as *"invalid XPath query"* nor *"invalid search/selector"*; there is no error data type.

Comment: @Alejandro: The OP claims that some value(s) of `xpathExpression` cause fatal errors with: "The expression is not a legal expression.".  So if the OP's reports are correct, then there certainly are invalid XPath queries.  In fact, 2 seconds of trial and error is enough to prove the absurdity of your claim that XPath does not throw exceptions on invalid values of `xpathExpression`. Set `xpathExpression` to "" or "1a", for example.

Comment: @Brock Adams: "The expression is not a legal expression" means it's not syntactically correct. Neither your examples "" nor "1a". **All `xpath` questions are about XPath expression. Where is the xpath expression here?**

Comment: @Alejandro: **`xpathExpression` is the xpath expression here**.   It is a variable that can be one of many valid or invalid values. This question is about how to detect and/or deal with invalid xpath expressions, as stated before.  Also as stated before, the OP would have to provide more specific details, but that is hardly necessary in the general case.  We seem to have come full circle in this comment exchange.  Kindly defer to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

`try/catch` should really be used as a last resort when you cannot predict how an error can occur.

consider this instead:

```
if (typeof xpathExpression !== "undefined" && xpathExpression !== "") {
    document.evaluate(
        xpathExpression,
        document,
        null,
        XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
        null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap it in a `try-catch` block:

```
try {
  document.evaluate(...);
} catch (ex) {
  // something went wrong
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instantiate the variable xpathExpression and then you may use:

```
if (xpathExpression)
document.evaluate(...);
```

no need of try/catch block

Comment: This is Ben's answer. And, from the OP, `xpathExpression` is not empty, it is some invalid string/selector.

Comment: what is the point of having a invalid expression and stop it using try-catch block ? why not just fix the expression ?

Comment: I agree, but sometimes people find it easier to TEST that the expression is invalid using a try-catch block.